# Is there any way to add MultiPolyline component using react-leaflet?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet, openstreetmap, react-leaflet

I am trying to implement an OpenSteetMap view using leaflet.
I have created a [POC for the same](http://jsfiddle.net/jeffjohny/6pfh2okj/14/).

```
var map = L.map('map').setView([9.89445, 76.71272], 12).addLayer(osm);
var latlngs1 = [
    [[9.84644243, 76.81231223],
    [9.91437659, 76.82216573]],
    [[9.86079307, 76.69274206],
    [9.9061336, 76.69914242]]
];
var latlngs2 = [
    [[9.91437659, 76.82216573],
    [9.86079307, 76.69274206]]
];
var polyline1 = L.multiPolyline(latlngs1, {color: 'red'}).addTo(map);
var polyline2 = L.multiPolyline(latlngs2, {color: 'green'}).addTo(map);
```

Since i am using Reactjs to create the application, i started using react-leaflet library which provide react components.

But i am not able to find MulitPolyline component in react-leaflet. [Doc](https://react-leaflet.js.org/docs/en/components.html) seems like there is no support for MultiPolyline.

Is there any way to add this component in React?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated leaflet library to latest version. Instead of multiPolyline used polyLine and it works fine

```
var map = L.map('map').setView([9.89445, 76.71272], 12).addLayer(osm);
var latlngs1 = [
[[9.84644243, 76.81231223],
[9.91437659, 76.82216573]],
[[9.86079307, 76.69274206],
[9.9061336, 76.69914242]]
];
var latlngs2 = [
[[9.91437659, 76.82216573],
[9.86079307, 76.69274206]]
];
var polyline1 = L.polyline(latlngs1, {color: 'red'}).addTo(map);
var polyline2 = L.polyline(latlngs2, {color: 'green'}).addTo(map);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jeffjohny/wnrkq13o/1/